# Exact Beta Functions in Statistical Mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization

I'm looking for analytically solvable models in statistical mechanics (classical or quantum) or related areas such as solid state physics in which 
the beta function for a certain renormalization procedure (preferably but not necessarily real space normalization) is exactly known.

I'm looking forward to your responses.

Comment: The Ising model in one and two dimensions...?

Comment: Okay:) That's certainly true. Though I would be happy to find a non-standard example that also has a phase transition (not like Ising 1D) at some point in parameter space

Comment: Okay. :) I would also be interested in a non-standard example...

Comment: If you're not aware of it, you must check out [Baxter's book](http://www.amazon.com/Exactly-Solved-Statistical-Mechanics-Physics/dp/0486462714)!